# How to convert a Backbone Collection into an Ampersand one?

Tags: backbone.js, ampersand.js, ampersand-collection

I'm in the process of trying to convert a Backbone collection into an Ampersand one. Here's what I have so far (I'm also converting from requirejs to webpack using CommonJS along the way):
Backbone collection:

```
define([ 'backbone', 'models/loneItem'], function( Backbone, LoneItem ) {
  return Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: LoneItem,
    urlRoot: '/deeply/nested/path/',
    url: function() {
      return this.urlRoot + this.options.id + '/';
    },
    initialize: function(models, options) {
      this.options = options || {};
    },
    parse: function(response){
      return response.arrayAttribute;
    }
  });
});
```

and then in the view I'll instantiate it like so:

```
...
var myCollection = new GroupOfItems( [], { id: 'someID' } );
myCollection.fetch();
```

which would then produce a call to `/deeply/nested/path/someID/`, find the `arrayAttribute` in the returned data and transform its contents into a set of LoneItem models, accessible by `myCollection`.

For the Ampersand collection:

```
var Collection = require('ampersand-rest-collection');
var LoneItem = require('../models/LoneItem');

module.exports = Collection.extend({
  model: LoneItem,
  url: '/deeply/nested/path/',
  parse: function(response){
    return response.arrayAttribute;
  }
});
```

And its view:

```
...
var myCollection = new GroupOfItems();
myCollection.fetchById('someID');
```

The data being returned looks like this

```
{
  "arrayAttribute": [
    {"id": "stringID1", "title": "Title A"},
    {"id": "stringID2", "title": "Title B"}
  ]
}
```

It produces a successful XHR, but `myCollection` only becomes a collection object with a single member, one that has the default props from `LoneItem`. Is the issue that the data being returned has no `id` attribute set on the root level of the response? Or is there some difference between the Backbone and Ampersand collection implementations that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I should not have strayed so far from my original implementation:

```
var Collection = require('ampersand-rest-collection');
var LoneItem = require('../models/LoneItem');

module.exports = Collection.extend({
  model: LoneItem,
  urlRoot: '/deeply/nested/path/',
  url: function() {
    return this.urlRoot + this.options.id + '/';
  },
  initialize: function(models, options) {
    this.options = options || {};
  },
  parse: function(response){
    return response.arrayAttribute;
  }
});
```

From the view:

```
var myCollection = new GroupOfItems([], {id: 'someID'});
myCollection.fetch();
```

**In other words, all I had to do was simply change the Backbone.Collection to Ampersand and that's that.**

[`fetchById`](http://ampersandjs.com/docs#ampersand-rest-collection-fetchbyid%20'fetchById') is intended to get a member of the collection with a separate REST call.